# How to make HTTP Get request objective-c

Tags: objective-c, http, get, request, nsurlsession

I have a host where going my key and hid check.
Host is showing there are no any requests.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://host/key.php?keys=cf7dc026e243bf862d60256099a63e58n2gc49b56d84a2148c130d2c010ff87feb3f&hid=1"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request reply: %@", requestReply);
}] resume];
```

There is my Key.php, where is going check for key and hid.
All server code written on php.
Server is MySQL. Server encoding is a UTF8

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
ob_end_clean();
$response = null;
$license = R::findOne('license', ' key_code = ? ', array(
$_GET['keys']
));
 if (is_null($license)) $response = set_response(false, 400,         "Key doesnвЂ™t exist");
   else if(intval(strtotime($license->data_okonch))==0 ||         $license->hid == "nulled") $response = set_response(false, 400, "Key zeroed");
 else if (intval(strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) >      intval(strtotime($license->data_okonch))) 
 $response =set_response(false, 400, "License expired");
 {
 else if (is_null($license->hid))
 $license->hid = $_GET['hid'];
 R::store($license);
 $response = set_response(true, 200, "Successful. HID was updated");
}
else if (strval($_GET['hid']) == strval($license->hid))            $response = set_response(true, 200, "Successful, HID wasnвЂ™t updated");
else if (strval($_GET['hid']) != strval($license->hid))          $response = set_response(false, 400, "HID doesnвЂ™t match");
```

Once I finally sended request, I don’t know how. I don’t changed code and later it again doesn’t work

Comment: You put the key and hid in the URL? You don't put that into the headers? What's the doc of your API? Do you have a `cURL`, a Postman working? Ie, do you have "proof" it can work?

Comment: Larme, headers are need for POST Request, but I need GET

Comment: Headers can be put in get request too you know? We can't say what's wrong with your code, it's valid. You have a response: `NSLog(@"Request reply: %@", requestReply);`? Does it log something? What's the doc of your WebAPI? Because that's the important part. Server can implement anything...

Comment: I’m writing on iPad. And compiling through THEOS

Comment: No it doesn’t logging

Comment: Yes, I have [cURL]. I don’t know how to integrate this to my main code

Comment: If you have a working `cURL` command, edit your question with it...

Comment: I haven’t got command. Can u help me with this code?

Comment: What don't you understand in: It depends on what the server accepts/needs. So what's the doc for it? You can do anything, any encoding. It's like saying a phrase in the middle of a group. If we don't have context, no one will understand it/care about it.

Comment: Server MySQL, server encoding is a UTF-8 Unicode. All code on server written on php

Comment: There is a my key.php code

Comment: Edit your question with the PHP code then, it's unreadable in comment.

Comment: Check key.php code

Comment: Use https.  You're going to have problems issuing unencrypted requests unless you have explicitly configured the app to allow that.

Comment: Also, you'll have to retain the session somewhere or else the request will get cancelled as soon as the code above goes out of scope.